# Generating Unique Random ArrayList of values in Java

Tags: java, random

What would be the best way to generate 50,000 **unique** random values which are put into an ArrayList in Java?

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment. If is for plain curiosity, then your curiosity falls in the homework assignment as well. Do something first then you could have further guidance.

Comment: Values in what range?

Comment: The values should be alphanumeric so A-Z + a-z and 0-9

Comment: See Kayaman's answer, but I suspect you have more requirements you forgot to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill the ArrayList with 50,000 sequential values and call `Collections.shuffle(list)`.